# Simple state machine

Tags: beginner, c, state-machine

I tried implementing a state machine in C.
This is for a Stratosphere Balloon and I wanted to use a state machine to make it better.
This will be later implemented in ARM CMSIS.

The state function doesn't really do anything yet. And the `while(1)` loops will be replaced by the `sbRepeat` transition code.

```
#ifndef _SB_FSM
#define _SB_FSM

/**
 * Transition codes
 * used to navigate from current to the next state
 */
typedef enum state_transitions {
    sbStartupTrans,
    sbSelfTestTrans,
    sbStartupOK,
    sbErr,
    sbSelfTestOK,
    sbFlightStartOK,
    sbAscendOK,
    sbDescendOK,
    sbRecoveryOK,
    sbEndOK,
    sbAny,
    sbRepeat
}sbTransition;
/**
 * State Definitions
 */
typedef enum states {
    sbIdle,
    sbSelfTest,
    sbStartup,
    sbFlightStart,
    sbAscend,
    sbDescend,
    sbRecovery,
    sbError,
    sbEnd,
} sbState;

/**
 * State Transition definitions
 * when it encounter <trans> move to <state> State
 */
typedef struct state_trans {
    sbTransition trans;
    sbState state;
}sbStateTrans;

/**
 * State Definition
 * @param name - Name of the State
 * @param func - Function Handler of the State
 * @param transitions - Allowed Transition definitions 
 */
typedef struct state_def {
    char name[255];
    sbTransition (*func)(void);
    sbStateTrans transitions[16];
}sbStateDef;

sbTransition sbIdleState(void);
sbTransition sbSelfTestState(void);
sbTransition sbStartupState(void);
sbTransition sbFlightStartState(void);
sbTransition sbAscendState(void);
sbTransition sbDescendState(void);
sbTransition sbRecoveryState(void);
sbTransition sbErrorState(void);
sbTransition sbEndState(void);

sbState fetchNextState(sbState, sbTransition);

/**
 * Structure: {<state name>, <function pointer> , transitions{{<encounters> -> <next state>}}
 */
static sbStateDef states[9] = {
    {"Idle", sbIdleState,                {{sbStartupTrans, sbStartup}, {sbSelfTestTrans, sbSelfTest}}},
    {"Self Test", sbSelfTestState,       {{sbStartupTrans, sbStartup}, {sbErr, sbIdle}}},
    {"Startup", sbStartupState,          {{sbStartupOK, sbFlightStart}, {sbErr, sbIdle}}},
    {"Flight Start", sbFlightStartState, {{sbFlightStartOK, sbAscend}, {sbErr, sbError}}},
    {"Ascend", sbAscendState,            {{sbAscendOK, sbDescend}, {sbErr, sbError}, {sbRepeat, sbAscend}}},
    {"Descend", sbDescendState,          {{sbDescendOK, sbRecovery}, {sbErr, sbError}, {sbRepeat, sbDescend}}},
    {"Recovery", sbRecoveryState,        {{sbRecoveryOK, sbEnd}, {sbErr, sbError}, {sbRepeat, sbRecovery}}},
    {"Error", sbErrorState,              {{sbRepeat, sbError}}},
    {"End", sbEndState,                  {}}
};


#endif
```

This is the .c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "sb_fsm.h"

/**
 * Idle state to take commands
 * @returns sbTransition - Transition code
 */
sbTransition sbIdleState(void) {
    int err = 1;  
    while(1) {
        char *input = malloc(255 * sizeof(char));
        printf("Idle State\n");
        printf("> ");
        scanf("%s", input); 
        getc(stdin);
        if (strcmp(input, "startup") == 0){
            return sbStartupTrans;
        } else if (strcmp(input, "selftest") == 0) {
            return sbSelfTestTrans;
        } else if (strcmp(input, "help") == 0) {
            printf("<startup>   : Initialize the startup procedure\n");
            printf("<selftest>  : Initialize module check\n");
            continue;
        }
        printf("\ntype 'help' to get the commands\n");
    }
}

/**
 * Self Test or Self Diagnosis Check to test if all the 
 * components are working well
 * <br>
 * Returns <sbSelfTestOK> on success,
 * <sbErr> on failure
 * @returns sbTransition - Transition code
 */
sbTransition sbSelfTestState(void) {
    int err = 0;
    while (1) {
        printf("Self Test\n");
        if (err == 0) {
            return sbStartupTrans;
        } else if (err == 1) {
            return sbErr;
        }
    }
}

sbTransition sbStartupState(void) {
    int err = 0;
    while (1) {
        printf("Startup State\n");
        if (err == 0) {
            return sbStartupOK;
        } else {
            return sbErr;
        }
    }
}

sbTransition sbFlightStartState(void) {
    int err = 0;
    while (1) {
        printf("Flight Start\n");
        if (err == 0) {
            return sbFlightStartOK;
        } else {
            return sbErr;
        }
    }
}

sbTransition sbAscendState(void) {
    int err = 0;
    printf("Ascend State\n");
    if (err == 0) {
        return sbAscendOK;
    } else if (err == 1) {
        return sbRepeat;
    } else {
        return sbErr;
    }
}

sbTransition sbDescendState(void) {
    int err = 0;
    while (1) {
        printf("Descend State\n");
        if (err == 0) {
            return sbDescendOK;
        } else {
            return sbErr;
        }
    }
}

sbTransition sbRecoveryState(void) {
    int err = 0;
    while (1) {
        printf("Recovery State\n");
        if (err == 0) {
            return sbRecoveryOK;
        } else {
            return sbErr;
        }
    }
}

sbTransition sbErrorState(void) {
    int err = 0;
    while (1) {
        printf("Error State\n");
        return sbAny;
    }
}

sbTransition sbEndState(void) {
    printf("Accepted\n");
    char *input = malloc(255 * sizeof(char));
    while(1) {
        printf("> ");
        scanf("%s", input);
        getc(stdin); 
        if (strcmp(input, "restart") == 0) {
            return sbEndOK;
        }
    }
    return sbErr;
}


sbState fetchNextState(sbState state, sbTransition ret) {
    
    int i,j;
    i = 0;
    while (i < sizeof(states[state].transitions)/sizeof(sbStateTrans)) {
        if (ret == states[state].transitions[i].trans) {
            return states[state].transitions[i].state;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return sbError;
}
```

This is the main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sb_fsm.h"
#include <unistd.h>

void delay(unsigned long ms);

int main(void) {
    
    sbState curr_state = sbIdle;  
    
    sbTransition (*run_func)(void);
    while (1) {
        sbTransition ret = states[curr_state].func();

        curr_state = fetchNextState(curr_state, ret);
        delay(500);
    }

    return 0;
}

void delay(unsigned long ms) {
    usleep(ms * 1000);
}
```

Hoping on getting some advice on how to improve it.

Comment: I'm assuming "ARM CMSIS" means a bare metal Cortex M embedded system with microcontroller? Or is this for a high end, PC-like ARM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing state machines with a table with function pointers is very common. The table should however be read-only and preferably stored in flash. This does however seem to be some PC-like ARM with Linux?

The design with a centralized state transition decision-maker is particularly important and your program is well-written there. Picking next state, based on the result from the previous, should be done at one single place in the program, not in each individual state ("stateghetti programming"). With a centralized decision-maker, you can also easily implement a safe mode for the program where it goes upon certain critical errors.

Regarding the state machine/array:

- `typedef enum state_transitions` - the enum tag `state_transitions` is useless and can be removed.
- At the end of `sbState` enum, include a member for size such as `sbStates` or what you wish to call it. Then change the `states[9]` to `states[]` and `static_assert(sizeof states/sizeof *states == sbStates, "states data inconsistent");` to guarantee data integrity.
- Assuming `char name[255];` will never change, then 255 bytes per array item is wasteful. A `char*` to a string literal will save loads of read-only memory over this.
- `states` should be `const`.

So you could instead have something like:

```
static const sbStateDef states[] = {
    [sbIdle] =        {"Idle", sbIdleState,           {{sbStartupTrans, sbStartup}, {sbSelfTestTrans, sbSelfTest}}},
    [sbSelfTest] =    {"Self Test", sbSelfTestState,  {{sbStartupTrans, sbStartup}, {sbErr, sbIdle}}},
    ...
};
static_assert(sizeof states/sizeof *states == sbStates, "states data inconsistent"); // C11
```

You can do similar with `transitions`. Overall, designated array initializers like above, that make use of the enum is strongly recommended for readability and data integrity.

General comments:

- Never define variables in header files, ever. If you ever find yourself with the need to define a variable in a header, something has gone fundamentally wrong in your program design. In this case you could probably put both the allocation of the state machine and the calling code in main.c.
- All the `while(1)` loops mean that you can't change states... I'm assuming this is just place-holders? Such loops are unacceptable in a hosted multi-process system such as Linux. You should probably consider porting this to pthreads and put the thread to sleep when it isn't working.

Comment: Thank you very very much for the review and the advice.

Comment: I will use the ARM Cortex M Boards for my project and many of the things will be reworked later on.
This is indeed very very helpful to get used to design patterns. I just got into C and this is very useful to better know more professional design patterns.

I will change the code accordingly.
The `while(1);` is indeed just a placeholder.
especially the advice with the `state` array is very helpful. I did not really know if this is good coding style.

Would you say that the general design is good?

Comment: And really thanks for taking time and writing a review and advice

Comment: @SL7Bot This code that you have written can't be used in bare metal microcontrollers - you have written code for a PC. So my review is assuming that a PC will be used. The advise to use pthreads is made assuming you'd use Linux.

Comment: Yeah many of the used functions are just as placeholders, like the scanf()
I will then rework the whole thing to fit in onto a microcontroller